# Is it possible to create dynamic in-memory and storage array in soldiity?

Tags: arrays, memory, memory-management, solidity

I would like to implement something like:

```
uint DEFAULT_SIZE = 20;
byte256[] arr = new byte256[](DEFAULT_SIZE);

function push(byte256 item) public {
  bool isTimeToResize = arr[arr.length - 1] != 0;
  if (isTimeToResize) {
    byte256[] temp = new byte256[](arr.length + DEFAULT_SIZE);
    arr = copyOldArrayIntoBiggerOne(arr, temp);
  }
}
```

The issue is I am not sure this operations would not override memory below origin array default size.

There is no such thing like dynamic resizable arrays and at the same time the compiler allows potentially dangerous operations with array definition and usage. [Source docs.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40115)

Compared with java memory management there is no such thing like a garbage collector, all allocated memory is never reclaimed back at least at this point of development. [Source docs.](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/internals/layout_in_memory.html)

Based on my understanding memory for array in **solidity** is allocated with one-by-one. It means pushing an item behind origin, e.g. 20, slots would potentially override code places below, but something like `OutOfBoundException` would not be thrown.

I would be glad if you have more information regarding memory allocation for arrays of primitives and structure which should help answer this and similar questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far the best information about data structure memory management in solidity has been found in this [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HkpCbY7TdlxQbkSK1az0kj_bY_Cxs-QA/view):

> Dynamic Arrays
> Values for (uint256[] private arrayUint256;) are stored at locations:
> storage[keccak256(storage slot number)+key] = value
>
> Note: ● The number of elements in the dynamic array is stored at
> storage[storage slot number]

Out of memory case:

> Memory Expansion Could you write some code that:

```
Push32 0xFFFFFFF....FFFFF A BIG NUMBER 
Push8 0x00
MSTORE
```

> & hope to crash the EVM by doing out of memory.

> But: ● Each word that memory expands costs Gas. ● Requesting a LOT of
> memory will cause an out of gas error.

Update: more information has been found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q5GGuc2MNWrIUqwGX0wsNuTrygCJv4EH/view).

> Storage layout
>
> String/Bytes Type
>
> • Special dynamic array
>
> • If less than 31 bytes, its data are stored in the same position, p,
> as its length
>
> • Else the rules of dynamic arrays apply
>
> Dynamic Array
>
> • A storage slot that holds its length is initialized at some
> position, p
> • The array’s data are stored starting at position
> keccack(p)